# Reccurance relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

Hi I need help with this relation.:

$$a(n)+4a(n-1)+4a(n-2)=2n-1,$$ $a(1)=2, a(2)=4$

I've been trying to solve it for days. On Wolfram Alpha I'm getting the following:

$$\frac{59}{36}(-2)^n - \frac{263}{108}(-2)^n + (-1)^{2n}\left(\frac{2}{9}n+\frac{5}{27}\right)$$

And I'm getting

$$\frac{59}{36}(-2)^n - \frac{263}{108}(-2)^n + \frac{2}{9}n+\frac{5}{27}$$

So where did the $(-1)^{2n}$ come from?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It would probably help if you explain how you got to that answer.

Comment: P(n)=A(n)+B
put that in equation An+b+4(A(n-1)+B)....=2n-1
Results A=2/9, B=5/27
a(n)=c1(-2)^n+c2(-2)^n+(2/9)n+5/27

Comment: Since $a(n)$ seems to only exist for integer $n$ and $(-1)^{2n}=1$ for all integer $n$, I think your answer matches Wolfram Alpha's result, though I'm not sure why it still kept the$(-1)^{2n}$ term (possibly a glitch?)

Comment: I'm wondering if I used the wrong formula
an-b  => An+B
what if it's something like (b^an)(An+B)? And why if it is

Answer (score 0):

You and wolfram get the same, since $(-1)^{2n}=1$ for all $n.$

Comment: But why was it written there? And where from did they get it?

Comment: @IsusvonBier Maybe Wolfram Alpha didn't simplify the result?

Comment: This was the result they gave:
a(n) = 1/108 (4 (-1)^(2 n) (6 n + 5) + (-2)^n (177 n - 263))